# Typesetting Greek characters in bibliography

Tags: fonts, biblatex, greek

I've been struggling with trying to get Greek characters to typeset in my bibliography for a while now, but can't seem to find a solution that works for me.

Here is a MWE of the `.tex` I am working with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is the citation: \cite{duchowski_2012}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the relevant entry in `library.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{duchowski_2012,
    title = {τεχνη Photons: Evolution of a Course in Data Structures},
    pages = {49-56},
    booktitle = {Eurographics 2012-Education Papers},
    author = {Duchowski, Andrew T.},
    date = {2012}
}
```

After running XeLaTeX and Biber, the `.bbl` file has the Greek characters correct.  However,  running XeLaTeX the second time, the typeset citation is:

[1] A. T. Duchowski. “ Photons: Evolution of a Course in Data Structures”. In: Eurographics 2012- Education Papers. 2012, pp. 49–56.

and the `.log` file has these lines:

```
 [1]
Missing character: There is no τ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ε in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no χ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ν in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no η in font cmr10!
```

The problem is, I am restricted to Times New Roman or Computer Modern for the majority of the document.  I'm sure there is an exception for typesetting the Greek characters, but I don't want to change the font of the entire bibliography.  Any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: Do you need only those characters? If yes, why not type them in math mode? Use `{$....$}`

Comment: Are you running XeLaTeX without `\usepackage{fontspec}`?

Comment: @egreg: The package `inputenc` is loaded so I guess Rakurai is using pdflatex. However your package `newunicodechar` is the right choice.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The body of the question refers to XeLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. Sorry.

Comment: If it's just that one, I suggest that you turn it into: `${\tau}{\epsilon}{\chi}{\nu}{\eta}$`.  It's sad for a Greek to suggest this, but it's the easiest fix and it will work in normal LaTeX too.  Otherwise, use XeLaTeX with `fontspec` (not `inputenc`) and a font with Greek characters, e.g., `\setromanfont{Free Serif}`.  In this case, you may want to capitalize and to add the accent too: `Τέχνη`.

Comment: @egreg: I was using XeLaTeX because I had read that it supported Unicode.

Comment: @nickie: Thank you, I just added the math mode characters and it works.  I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't need a fix every time I export my library from Zotero, but I don't really want to mess with the overall font for this particular document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XeLaTeX you mustn't use `inputenc`; for getting full Unicode support, `fontspec` is needed instead. However, the default font you get is Latin Modern (very similar to Computer Modern) which hasn't Greek letters. You can get by with `ucharclasses`

```
% this is just for getting a self-contained example
% use you normal library.bib file also in \addbibresource
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{duchowski_2012,
    title = {τεχνη Photons: Evolution of a Course in Data Structures},
    pages = {49-56},
    booktitle = {Eurographics 2012-Education Papers},
    author = {Duchowski, Andrew T.},
    date = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% load fontspec for OpenType support
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

% Since the font has no lowercase Greek, load also ucharclasses
\usepackage[Greek]{ucharclasses}

% bibliography package
\usepackage{biblatex}

% define a font with Greek support
% depending on your setup you might need to type
% \newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{cmunrm.otf}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{CMU Serif}

% when Greek is found, change to \greekfont    
\setTransitionsForGreek{\begingroup\greekfont}{\endgroup}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is the citation: \cite{duchowski_2012}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick with `ucharclasses` shouldn't be necessary if you use an OpenType version of Times that has Greek glyphs.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{duchowski_2012,
    title = {τεχνη Photons: Evolution of a Course in Data Structures},
    pages = {49-56},
    booktitle = {Eurographics 2012-Education Papers},
    author = {Duchowski, Andrew T.},
    date = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is the citation: \cite{duchowski_2012}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]